# JBuilder not rendering anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I've started a new rails 4 app and want to use it as an API. So this is what I got:

`app/controllers/api/v1/teams_controller.rb`:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class TeamsController < ApplicationController
      ...

      def show
        @team = Team.find(params[:id])
      end

      ...
    end
  end
end
```

`app/views/api/v1/teams/show.json.jbuilder`:

```
team ||= @team

json.id team['id']
json.name team['name']
```

and I get a blank page rendered.

However, when I add `render json: @team` to the `show` method it gets rendered normally.

Anyone has an idea whats wrong with JBuilder?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Were you eventually able to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I had to use `render`

Comment: How did you try to access the json view? Via browser or via curl GET request?

Comment: Also, have you been using the `rails-api` gem by any chance?

Comment: I tried it both ways and both only worked with `render. On another, more recent project, I used rails-api and it worked great.

Comment: I was asking about `rails-api` since I had the same problem as you had, and later found out that the implicit render module has been removed from `rails-api` and needs to be added back by including `ActionController::ImplicitRender`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I added `format: 'json'` to my route:

```
get '/api/stuff', to: 'stuff#show', format: 'json'
```

Hope that helps.